# Date behaves differently in column and form field

Tags: magento-1.8, adminform, date

Date stored in database: 2014-02-07 00:00:00

Magento Timezone: IST (GMT +5.30)

When I display this in column - it displays - 2014-02-07 05:30:00 which is correct and expected (since magento stores dates in UTC).

However, when I try to display the same date in textbox (readonly), it displays 2014-02-07 00:00:00 i.e. exactly same as in database - without any conversion.

How can I convert the date to show correct value in textbox?

`$fieldset->addField('end_date', 'date', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('survey')->__('End Date'),
            'index'     => 'end_date',
            'name'      => 'end_date',
            'class'     => 'readonly',
            'readonly'  => true,
            'format' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT),
      ));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve this by changing the date before setting the form data in controller.

```
if($model['start_date'] != null)
    $model['start_date'] = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($model['start_date']));

if($model['end_date'] != null)
    $model['end_date'] = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($model['end_date']));

Mage::register('survey_data', $model);
```

And in block, I am displaying it as simple text (since it is readonly it doesn't make any difference)

```
 $fieldset->addField('end_date', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('survey')->__('End Date'),
            'index'     => 'end_date',
            'name'      => 'end_date',
            'class'     => 'readonly',
            'readonly'  => true,
      ));
```

Also, I unset the date variable so that the date shown in display shouldn't be saved in db.

```
unset($data['start_date']);
unset($data['end_date']);
```

Thanks smiggle for giving me the direction :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the best solution, but I think it should work:

Add a custom renderer to the textfield that will format the date:

```
$renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('foo/widget_grid_renderer_date');
$fieldset->addField('end_date', 'text', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('survey')->__('End Date'),
            'index'     => 'end_date',
            'name'      => 'end_date',
            'class'     => 'readonly',
            'readonly'  => true
      )
    )->setRenderer($renderer);
```

Create a new renderer class:

```
class Example_Foo_Block_Widget_Grid_Renderer_Date extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template 
    implements Varien_Data_Form_Element_Renderer_Interface
{

    public function render() {

        //...
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/locale')
                        ->date($data, Zend_Date::ISO_8601, null, false)->toString($format);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this function will return correct date but still the question is how to just display converted date in the textbox( $fieldset->addField )

Comment: wow, the updated solution is nice.. though I ended up fixing it by changing the date while setting up the form. I'll post my new code as answer shortly